# Simulate shell behavior (force eval of last command to be displayed)

Tags: python, c

In a python shell, if I type `a = 2` nothing is printed. If I type `a` 2 gets printed automatically. Whereas, this doesn't happen if I run a script from idle.

I'd like to emulate this shell-like behavior using  the python C api, how is it done?

For instance, executing this code `PyRun_String("a=2 \na", Py_file_input, dic, dic);` from C, will not print anything as the output. 
I'd like to simulate a shell-like behavior so that when I execute the previous command, the value "2" is stored in a string. Is it possible to do this easily, either via python commands or from the C api? Basically, how does the python shell do it?

Comment: [`PyRun_InteractiveLoop`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_InteractiveLoop)? That'll get you an actual interactive prompt, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile your code so expression statements invoke `sys.displayhook`, you need to pass `Py_single_input` as the `start` parameter, and you need to provide one statement at a time.

Comment: So you're not allowed to define à fonction in that mode? Or IS line break still allowed ?

Comment: @lezebulon: A function definition is one statement (compound statements are okay). I don't think you can put empty lines in your compound statements, though.

Comment: Also, what if I want to store the résultats string in memory and not peint it to std::coût? Thanks!

Comment: @lezebulon: In that case, you should write Python code that does that, rather than trying to convince Python to handle expression statements differently. Strictly speaking, you *could* set a `sys.displayhook` that does that, but I'd recommend against it.